# give each wedge a different label in style=wedged in DOT graphviz

Tags: graphviz, dot

I could not figure out looking at the Graphviz docs if there is a way to specify different labels for each wedge in a circle with `style=wedged`. e.g. below node draws a circle divided into 3 wedges with three colors.

```
nodepie  [shape = "circle" style = "wedged" fillcolor = "green:red:yellow"];
```

I want to put different numbers on each wedge.
Could anybody help?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but I don't think this is possible; I've tried before.  Even using weird combinations of html labels I wasn't able to get a satisfactory result.  There's nothing in the `label` documentation that even hints at a method for achieving this.

Sorry I don't have a more positive answer for you, but in the case I think it's "no."  As you can see, alignment is a mess; it **might** be feasible if the pie had four wedges and the html label could be superimposed on top, two rows and two columns.  But with three it's hard to imagine a layout that would delight:

```
digraph x{
nodepie  [shape = "circle" style = "wedged" fillcolor = "green:red:yellow" 
label=< <TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0"> <TR><TD PORT="f0">one</TD><TD>two</TD></TR> </TABLE>>];
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you again. Your answer at least confirmed that it cannot be done. In addition, due to your sample code above, I now know that it can be done if the pie has only two wedges, which I tried below. nodepie3 [shape = "circle" style = "wedged" fillcolor = "green;0.5:red;0.5" 
label=<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0"><TR><TD>green</TD> </TR><TR><TD>red</TD> </TR> </TABLE>>];

Comment: I don't know what is happening at the comment editor, when I type enter, it just posts the comment instead of going to the next line.

Comment: The first comment I wrote above was incomplete. It got posted on Enter. I cannot edit it anymore somehow. I also wanted to ask this question to TomServo (or anyone) in that comment: the circle with 2 wedges gets drawn with horizontal slices. Is there a way to make it vertical? Thanks.

Comment: @sof977  Glad my example shed at least some light on your problem.  The documentation is mute on how to affect the orientation of the wedges; I've looked into that before also.  If my answer and research has helped you in any way please [take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) thanks and good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Workaround for three wedgets (of approximately same size);

```
digraph x{
nodepie  [shape = "circle" style = "wedged" fillcolor = "green:red:yellow" 
label=< 
<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="0" CELLSPACING="0"> 
<TR>
<TD PORT="f0" ROWSPAN="2">one</TD>
<TD ROWSPAN="2">&nbsp;</TD>
<TD>two</TD>
</TR> 
<TR>
<TD PORT="f0">tree</TD>
</TR> 
</TABLE>
>];
}
```

[image: pie with 3 wedged and text on each]

Answer (score 0):

If you create a html-table with elements using the same colors as the WEDGE, you can have your labels next to the pie.

```
digraph structs {
    
    p01 [shape = none
        label = <<table border="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr><td bgcolor="blue">P01</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="red">P02</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="yellow">P03</td></tr>
            <tr><td bgcolor="green">P04</td></tr>
            </table>>]
    node [shape=circle]
    pie [label="wedged"
        style=wedged
        color=none
        fillcolor="blue;0.4:red;0.1:yellow;0.2:green"
        fontcolor=pink]  
}
```

Result:
[image]