# Fill networkx nodes with percentage amount of color

Tags: python, networkx

i have a networkx graph and i want to fill the nodes inside the graph with a specific amount of color. I know about the fillstyle parameter, but there's no possibility to specify the fillstyle with percentage. Have anyone an idea how to solve this?

Comment: what percentage? What do you expect? Maybe draw image with expected result. And it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy and test it.

Comment: as  I know `networkx` uses `matplotlib` to draw it - and `matplotlib` has [Arc](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Arc.html) and you could use it to draw nodes separatelly.

Comment: you could also try [Pie](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.pie.html) or [Wedge](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.patches.Wedge.html?highlight=wedge#matplotlib.patches.Wedge)

Answer (score 0):

NetworkX library can use [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/), so you can use some of the Graphviz [DOT](https://graphviz.org/doc/info/lang.html) syntax and specify the attributes [`striped` or `wedged`](https://graphviz.org/docs/attr-types/style/) for nodes.
Example:

```py
import networkx as nx

G = nx.Graph()

G.add_node('Pie', label='', shape='circle', style='wedged, filled', fillcolor='violet;0.2:orange;0.3:lime')
G.add_node('Box A', label='', shape='box', style='striped', fillcolor='black;0;25:lime;0.5:cyan;0.25')
G.add_node('Box B', shape='plaintext', label="""<<TABLE BORDER="0" CELLBORDER="1" CELLSPACING="0">
        <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="10" WIDTH="100" BGCOLOR="black"> </TD></TR>
        <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="20" WIDTH="100" BGCOLOR="LIME"> </TD></TR>
        <TR><TD  FIXEDSIZE="true" HEIGHT="30" WIDTH="100" BGCOLOR="CYAN"> </TD></TR>
    </TABLE>>""")
pos = {'Pie':(0,0), 'Box A':(0,1), 'Box B':(0,2)}

nx.draw_networkx(G, with_labels=False, pos=pos)

A = nx.nx_agraph.to_agraph(G)
A.draw("nx_graph.png", prog="dot")
```

Result:
[image]

P.S. Adding labels on pie parts is more complicated than on a rectangle, but you can take advantage of this question: [give each wedge a different label in style=wedged in DOT graphviz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45803261/give-each-wedge-a-different-label-in-style-wedged-in-dot-graphviz)

P.S.: In the process the following warnings are displayed, but the output picture is still ok:

```bash
lib\site-packages\pygraphviz\agraph.py:1402: RuntimeWarning: Warning: cell size too small for content
Warning: cell size too small for content
in label of node Box B
Warning: More than 2 colors specified for a gradient - ignoring remaining

  warnings.warn(b"".join(errors).decode(self.encoding), RuntimeWarning)
```